# Sorting Numbers within an array [Batch Script]

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create an array that sorts numbers. It doesn't give me an error message but instead an infinite loop of the input numbers trying to do something.
I need to sort the numbers in the array using this method but I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set n=
set n=1
rem *** Section 1 "Input data into num array"
:Input
set v=
set /p v=enter a value:
if !v!== goto Input
set /a v=!v!
set num[!n!]=
set num[!n!]=!v!
set /a n=!n!+1
if !n! lss 6 goto Input
set /a n=!n!-1

rem *** Section 2 "comparing array value"
:A
set i=0

:B
set i=!i!+1
set swp=0
echo !num[%i%]! gtr !num[%j%]! goto D
set /a j=!i!+1
if !num[%i%]! gtr !num[%j%]! goto D

rem *** Section 3 "NO Swap needed"
:E
if !j! lss !n! goto B
rem *** Section 4 "Swap needed"
:D
set swp=1
set tmp=!num[%i%]!
set num[!i!]=!num[%j%]!
set num[!j!]=!tmp!
echo !num[!i!]!, !num[%j%]!
if !j! lss !n! goto B
goto A

:X
!echo[1]!
!echo[2]!
!echo[3]!
!echo[4]!
!echo[5]!
pause
endlocal
```

Comment: `if !v!== goto Input` cannot work, this is wrong syntax, so use `if not defined v goto Input` instead...

Comment: Also, what is this `set /a v=!v!` supposed to be doing? You're not performing any arithmetic, so do not require the `/a` option. `/a` doesn't change the variable object type from string to numeric, the value is still a string, _(just a string made up of digits)_. This, `set /a n=!n!+1` should be either `set /a n=n+1` or `set /a n+=1` and `set /a n=!n!-1` should be `set /a n=n-1` or `set /a n-=1`.

Comment: Just in case you don't notice it when correcting the syntax to match my above comment, you've also missed the `/a` option here, `set i=!i!+1`, _which should read `set /a i +=1`_.

Comment: `!echo[1]!` ???